# How to get distinct combination of three columns regardless of order?

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table (tablename) with three columns:

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C |
| A | C | B |
| A | B | D |

I want the output as:

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C |
| A | B | D |

That is, I want the unique combination of values from three columns regardless of which column they are in

Note: The above values are just as an example. My table contains many order combinations

Comment: SQL Server or Hive? They are different products.

Comment: I am using hive sql

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the columns to an array, sort it, take out the elements, and then use DISTINCT.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  c_array[0] AS c1,
  c_array[1] AS c2,
  c_array[2] AS c3
FROM
(
  SELECT sort_array(array(c1, c2, c3)) AS c_array FROM tablename
)
  collapsed
```

Answer (score -1):

select * from tblname where c1='A' and c2='B'

you can get the output as mentioned above by using this where condition

Comment: NO ! My table has many values, not just A and B. This was just as an example !